# backup postgresql via docker exec

Tags: postgresql, docker

How would you go about taking automatic rotated backups of a postgresql database running inside a docker 1.3 container? I'm mostly interested in the overall approach vs. the details of actual the backup commands themselves.

I am thinking about updating [this autobackup script](https://gist.github.com/matthewlehner/3091458), which has apparently been around since 2005. My current plan is

- Install the script in cron.daily on the docker host
- Have the script use direct local filesystem access for the rotation logic to handle the existence tests, `mkdir` and `rm` commands
- use `docker exec containername` to run the `psql` and `pg_dump` commands within the container, probably sending the stdout content to the docker host filesystem in the correct place via shell redirection

Answer (score -1):

The autobackup script is nice but don't verget to make a backup of the users and passwords:
pd_dumpall -g
If you don't need seperate backups of each database inside postgresql, it's eysier to use pg_dumpall.